# How can I fix this PDL installation?

Tags: macos, perl, installation, pdl

I have installed [PDL](http://pdl.perl.org) on a Mac OS X (10.7.3) machine. Evidently the SciPDL installer places `PDL.pm` in `/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level`, so I added

```
use lib '/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level';
```

at the top of my test script. I now get these errors:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _Perl_Gthr_key_ptr
  Referenced from: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/PDL/Core/Core.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _Perl_Gthr_key_ptr
  Referenced from: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/PDL/Core/Core.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Unfortunately these errors don't mean much to me. What do they mean? And what's the solution?

Comment: SciPDL is supposed to be a one-click installer for PDL on Macs, but as you indicate in your answer below installing from CPAN works, too. For anybody else who encounters trouble, feel free to hop on the PDL Users mailing list and let us know: http://pdl.perl.org/?page=mailing-lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cpanm` to install modules instead of the SciPDL installer. Install `cpanm`:

- either bootstrap from the Web:

  ```
  curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --self-upgrade
  ```
- or with the CPAN client that ships with Perl:

  ```
  cpan App::cpanminus
  ```

Install PDL:

```
cpanm PDL
```

This compiles PDL for your specific platform, making sure all the paths are set properly.

Comment: cpanm will not give you any of the graphics packages, unless you have already installed f77 and other libraries on which the pdl plot packages depend.